# парсинг файла с помощью boost::program_options

Tags: c++, парсер, boost

есть конфиг файл вида

`ip=192.168.1.1`

`port=10`

есть метод load который в идеале должен читать файл и парсить значения ip и port. имеет вид

```
void Config::load(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream config(filename);
    po::options_description desc("Port and ip");
    desc.add_options()
        ("ip", po::value<std::string>(), "ip address")
        ("port", po::value<short>(), "port");
    po::variables_map vm;

    if (config)
        po::store(po::parse_config_file(config, desc), vm);

    std::cout << vm["ip"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << vm["port"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;
}
```

и есть ошибка :) которая появляется при запуске скомпилированного файла.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
>     what():  boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибку нашел сам ) моя невнимательность.

поменял строчку

`std::cout << vm["port"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;`

на

`std::cout << vm["port"].as<short>() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Входные параметры:

```
--addr="192.168.0.1" 
--port="8080"
```

Код:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    po::options_description config("Conf");
    config.add_options()
                ("addr", po::value<std::string>()->required(), "IP address")
                ("port", po::value<std::string>()->required(), "Port")
                ;

    try 
    {
        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, config),vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        const std::string address = vm["addr"].as<std::string>();
        const std::string port = vm["port"].as<std::string>();

        std::cout << "address: " << address << std::endl;
        std::cout << "port: " << port << std::endl;
    } catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ссылка на [Wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wdP771TlF6G8q2UD)

P.S. На всякий случай уточню - код должен быть аналогичный, за исключением того, что Вы используете `parse_config_file` вместо `parse_command_line`, т.е. парсите содержимое файла, а не параметры комммандной строки.

Comment: спасибо, нашел причину ошибки сам :)